# how to add to count with SUM( ) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
select distinct b.actor_id
from actor b, rolee br, movie bm, movie_has_genre bmg, genre bg
where bmg.genre_id not in(select mg.genre_id
                         from actor a, rolee r, movie m, movie_has_genre mg, genre g
                           where a.actor_id = r.actor_id and r.movie_id = m.movie_id and m.movie_id = mg.movie_id and g.genre_id = mg.genre_id and a.actor_id = 3226)
and b.actor_id = br.actor_id and br.movie_id = bm.movie_id and bm.movie_id = bmg.movie_id and bmg.genre_id = bg.genre_id
and sum(count(distinct mg.genre_id) + count(distinct bmg.genre_id))>=7
group by b.actor_id
```

I have the above mysql query and what I need is, the total sum of a count bmg.genre_id and mg.genre_id. When I try this query I get INVALID USE OF GROUP FUNCTION ERROR 1111 .

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: What is the reason ?

Comment: @SalihK.Chousein Three-fold - 1. Human comprehensibility 2. Certainty of join hierarchy 3. Allows easy transition to other types of join (i.e. outer joins)

Answer (score 0):

Since sum is an aggregate function you can only use it with the having clause to filter group-wise.

```
select b.actor_id
from actor b, rolee br, movie bm, movie_has_genre bmg, genre bg
where bmg.genre_id not in(select mg.genre_id
                          from actor a, rolee r, movie m, movie_has_genre mg, genre g
                          where a.actor_id = r.actor_id and r.movie_id = m.movie_id and m.movie_id = mg.movie_id and g.genre_id = mg.genre_id and a.actor_id = 3226)
and b.actor_id = br.actor_id and br.movie_id = bm.movie_id and bm.movie_id = bmg.movie_id and bmg.genre_id = bg.genre_id
group by b.actor_id
having sum(count(distinct mg.genre_id) + count(distinct bmg.genre_id))>=7;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get error : 
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'mg.genre_id' in 'having .

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Group functions in WHERE clause.
Use HAVING clause for Group Functions.

Comment: I don't think the issue in Group by